# Check if all values of iterable are zero

Tags: python, iterable

Is there a good, succinct/built-in way to see if all the values in an iterable are zeros?  Right now I am using `all()` with a little list comprehension, but (to me) it seems like there should be a more expressive method.  I'd view this as somewhat equivalent to a `memcmp()` in C.

```
values = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
# Test if all items in values tuple are zero
if all([ v == 0 for v in values ]) :
    print 'indeed they are'
```

I would expect a built-in function that does something like:

```
def allcmp(iter, value) :
    for item in iter :
        if item != value :
            return False
    return True
```

Does that function exist in python and I'm just blind, or should I just stick with my original version?

## Update

I'm not suggesting that `allcmp()` is the solution. It is an example of what I *think* might be more meaningful.  This isn't the place where I would suggest new built-ins for Python.

In my opinion, `all()` isn't that meaningful.  It doesn't express what "all" is checking for.  You could assume that `all()` takes an iterable, but it doesn't express what the function is looking for (an iterable of `bool`s that tests all of them for `True`).  What I'm asking for is *some function like* my `allcmp()` that takes two parameters: an iterable and a comparison value.  I'm asking if there is a built-in function that does something similar to my made up `allcmp()`.

I called mine `allcmp()` because of my C background and `memcmp()`, **the name of my made up function is irrelevant** here.

Comment: **More** Expressive?!?!  `all([ v == 0 for v in values ])` is really very, very nice, clear, explicit and expressive.  How much better could it be?

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps I should have said more meaningful.  It might be because I am still somewhat new to Python, but to me that line would take a little time to decipher.  However, `if itercmp(values, 0)` seems more meaningful because I'd know quickly that I am comparing all values with 0.  Might just be my C background doing that though...

Comment: @mjschultz: "... I am comparing all values with 0" -- how do you know "all"? "iter" doesn't mean "all". Comparing with what purpose? Check if any zeroes? Check if all zeroes? Count the zeroes?

Comment: @ mjschultz: `itercmp(values, 0)` more "meaningful" than `all([ v == 0 for v in values ])`.  What?  How is that possible?  Please **update** your question with an explanation of how `itercmp` is somehow more expressive than `all()` and `0` is more expressive than `v == 0`.  I assume you're not kidding, so please **update** the question with an explanation of how this is an improvement.

Comment: "all() ... doesn't express what "all" means"?  Can't see the point you're trying to make.  Do you want `all` to be spelled "takes_an_iterable_of_bools_and_tests_all_of_them_for_True"?    Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: No, that would be stupid.  `alltrue()` would suffice, all would imply an iterable and true implies the test.  What I'm looking for is a general function that can test for more than just true.

I'll assume from your sarcastic answer that you don't know of one.

Comment: @ mjschultz: Sarcasm?  I don't think so.  I'm trying to actually understand your question.  Since `all` seems to be perfectly descriptive, I cannot understand your complaint.  Still.  So `allTrue` would be better than `all`?  Is that what you're saying?  What is this "general function" that tests for more than True.  True/False is the result of **all** possible comparison operators, so `all` applies to **all** possible logical tests.  What are you asking for?

Comment: I'm saying that `all()` is *not* perfectly descriptive.  `all(list)` doesn't mean anything and may or may not be correct, `alltrue(list)` tells me that we are looking to see if all values in `list` are true.  A general function would be `all(list, True)` meaning that all items in `list` are `True` or `all(list, 0)` meaning that all items in `list` are `0` or `all(list, 'ok')` meaning that all items in `list` are `'ok'`.  The question is: "Is there a good, succinct/built-in way to see if all the values in an iterable are zeros?"  I'm not sure where your confusion lies here.

Comment: @mjschultz: My confusion is simple. Given a single clear, simple, general function that can be applied to **all** possible predicates, you seem to be asking for a function that applies to only **one** specific predicate, `==`.  It doesn't seem sensible to ask for a function that applies to only **one** predicate when Python already has a function that already applies to **all** possible predicates.  I don't get the "please limit me to just one special-purpose predicate" behind the question.  What's the value in the limitation?

Comment: I believe `all()` only applies to "is true" predicate, you need to contort all the items in the list to have a truth value using a generator, which has the multiple predicate you are talking about.  I am okay with using the generator, but I was asking if there is a way to express it without the generator.  There is, in fact, a way to do that using numpy.array(), which probably build the generator automatically as part of `__cmp__`.

Comment: Please read edits to my answer.

Comment: any() seems to do this when used along with a 'not'.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Use generators rather than lists in cases like that:

```
all(v == 0 for v in values)
```

**Edit:**

`all` is standard Python built-in. If you want to be efficient Python programmer you should know probably more than half of them (http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html). Arguing that `alltrue` is better name than `all` is like arguing that C `while` should be call `whiletrue`. Is subjective, but i think that most of the people prefer shorter names for built-ins. This is because you should know what they do anyway, and you have to type them a lot.

Using generators is better than using numpy because generators have more elegant syntax. numpy may be faster, but you will benefit only in rare cases (generators like showed are fast, you will benefit only if this code is bottleneck in your program).

You probably can't expect nothing more descriptive from Python.

PS. Here is code if you do this in memcpm style (I like all version more, but maybe you will like this one):

```
list(l) == [0] * len(l)
```

Comment: Interesting, I was unaware of generators, thanks for that tidbit.

Comment: It seems to fairly directly express your intent as well.

Comment: Is there a faster approach for byte strings/bytearrays?

Answer (score 29):

If you know that the iterable will contain only integers then you can just do this:

```
if not any(values):
    # etc...
```

Comment: That is shorter, but I think it conceals the meaning behind what it does even more since it depends on values being `== 0`.

Comment: -1 By the time you have heavily commented the code so that it can be understood by non-sophists, you might as well have written 'all(v == 0 for v in values)` which is self-explanatory and future proof (when you decide that it should have been some integer other than zero).

Comment: code practices subjectivity aside, `if not any` is correct English as it is readable code. Furthermore, in certain applications like physics, where 0 is objectively known as "at rest" or "off", then this code is just as maintainable as it is readable.

Answer (score 10):

The any() function may be the most simple and easy way to achieve just that. If the iterable is empty,e.g. all elements are zero, it will return False.

```
values = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
print (any(values)) # return False
```

Comment: suggested to use `any()` instead of `all()` in consideration of (worst case) time scaling iterations - good answer.

Answer (score 8):

If values is a numpy array you can write

```
import numpy as np
values = np.array((0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
all(values == 0)
```

Comment: That `all` line is precisely as expressive and meaningful as I want.  I just wish it didn't rely on numpy. :(

Answer (score 3):

The built-in `set` is given an iterable and returns a collection (set) of unique values.

So it can be used here as:

```
set(it) == {0}
```

- assuming `it` is the iterable
- `{0}` is a set containing only zero

More info on python set-types-set-frozenset [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) in docs.

Comment: good use of datatype built-ins, but keep in mind this will lose index - if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using negation:

```
all(not v for v in values)
```