# Python all function is returning unexpected result

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the all function where I am evaluate if one item in the list would make the entire list false.
Where I am confused is the first print statement returns `false` which is correct but the second returns `True` which is incorrect to my understanding.  If all in the list are 0's then they both report true.  I don't understand why the second print outputs `true` when the list does not equal 0, because the last element is 1.

```
list_1 = [0,0,0,1]
print(all(ele == 0 for ele in list_1))
print(all(list_1) == 0)
```

Comment: Try `print(all(list_1))`

Comment: @Tomerikoo `print(all(list_1))` prints out `False`

Comment: So now doe this [Bool as int? How does python evaluate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30396171/6045800) answer your question?

Comment: Did you see this? [Check if all values of iterable are zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3525953/6045800)

Answer (score 0):

In the second instruction, `all(list_1)` is returning `False`.

This is false-like, as is 0, so when you test whether `all(list_1) == 0`, the answer is `True`.

```
print( all([1, 0, 1]) ) # -->  False
print( False == 0 )   # -->  True
```

#### Remember that in Python, False *does* `==` 0

What is not so obvious, perhaps, is that in Python, the equality test considers `False` to be equal to `0`. If you think it incorrect, here is the evidence:

[image]

Comment: The second instruction  `print(all(list_1) == 0)` returns `True` not `False`. If i would set `list_1=[0,0,0,0]` then both statements would return `True`.  Because both would evaluate to 0.  However with the list `list_1=[0,0,01]` the first returns false which is correct but the second returns `True` which is incorrect.  Because the expression does not equal 0.

Comment: @newdeveloper How is it not correct? You don't understand it maybe, but it does exactly what it's supposed to... [`all(list_1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) will return `False` as long as there is at least one `0`. `False` is equal to `0` while `True` is equal to `1`. When `all(list_1)` returns `False` and you check if it's `== 0` - that returns `True`. That is ***not*** the way to check if all elements of a list are `0`. The first line of code does that